# Is it legal to avoid the UK quarantine (August 2020) on passengers returning from France by traveling via another country?

Tags: uk, legal, france, covid-19, quarantine

I'm British, due to travel to the south of France for a week, flying from London to Turin (Italy) and driving across the border (it's the closest airport to my destination in France)

The UK has just (14 Aug) brought in travel restrictions requiring travelers from France to self-isolate.

Technically I will have 'traveled from Italy' when I return. From what I've read, I think this means that under UK rules I'm ***not*** legally obliged to self isolate on return.

Is this correct?

I'd like to cancel my trip, but this is further complicated my COVID-19 travel insurance refusing to refund anything because travel to/from Italy is not affected by the new restrictions.

Comment: Sounds like one for the Watchdogs to me.

Comment: Can you edit the question to say which part of the UK you will be returning to: England, Wales, Northern Ireland, or Scotland? Each one has its own health regulations.

Comment: Follow the spirit of the guidelines rather than trying to rules lawyer round the words.  Please don't kill my Dad.

Comment: @AdamBarnes - How on earth is this not the only answer to all of these ridiculous questions? I dealt with idiots a couple of days ago that think if the park has an unlocked gate that you're allowed in. (You're not). My statement of "A security system that does not prevent access is not the same as a sign that says Help Yourself" was met with much upset and crying. Some people!!

Comment: @enhzflep I guess people just don't want me to have a Father any more.

Comment: I'm from the US and drove my car in a round trip from Texas to Alabama and back a few months ago, ***just after*** Texas lifted such a quarantine for folks coming in from Louisiana.  Because COVID makes things unstable, I still worried Texas could change its mind suddenly during my two-week trip.  It would've been quicker to go to Alabama through Louisiana and come back the same way; but because of nearly the exact same concern you are expressing now, I took a "long cut" and went through Arkansas in both directions, adding both time and distance, but avoiding Louisiana entirely.

Comment: Your actual destination is France, of course, which is a little bit different than just passing through France.  But there are probably a lot of people with similar sorts of things on their minds.

Comment: When you fill the Visa & immigration office paperwork that is required to enter the country now (due to COVID), you will be asked about all the countries you've been in the last 14 days, so you will need to inform about your stay in France. Lying can give you a fine up to 3200£.

Comment: No, it's not legal, but if flying both to and from Turin, there's no way in practice UK authorities will know if you lie

Answer (score 55, accepted):

According to [Coronavirus (COVID-19): travel corridors](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-travel-corridors),

> You will need to self-isolate if you visited or made a transit stop in
> a country or territory that is not on the list in the 14 days before
> you arrive in England.

You would be OK if you spent 14 days in Italy after leaving France.

Comment: that pretty clear - I wonder if I can use that to help persuade my insurance to refund me.

Comment: @ConanTheGerbil Seems worth a try, especially if they are covering the whole trip, not just airfare.

Comment: @ConanTheGerbil [The FCO is currently advising against all but essential travel to France](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/france). That should normally be enough to get an insurance refund.

Comment: The FCO is the British Foreign & Commonwealth Office.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica - usually… but many have a new covid clause covering rapid changes in policy. Basically, you're supposed to know the situation could change at any time, therefore, you're at your own risk.

Comment: @Tetsujin depends when it was booked. If before the pandemic it should be covered. Anyone who booked travel after the pandemic can’t say they didn’t know there would be a risk of their plans being disrupted at short notice.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan if it’s just airfare that may be a challenge, as Conan is flying into Italy, not France, and Italy is still fine to travel to.

Comment: What about Wales, Northern Ireland, and Scotland?  This quote says "England", though I wouldn't be surprised if it's the same rule in each case.

Comment: @Panzercrisis Since the question did not specify, I went with the probabilities, given the population sizes.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Good point.

Comment: @Panzercrisis checking the guidance for [Wales](https://gov.wales/exemptions-self-isolation-coronavirus-covid-19-html), [Scotland](https://www.gov.scot/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-public-health-checks-at-borders/pages/exemptions/) and [Northern Ireland](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/coronavirus-covid-19-travel-advice) this rule is indeed the same.